# Carbon relay to aggregrator and shared cache configuration

Tags: graphite

Is it possible to setup carbon relay to forward to a cache and an aggregator and then have the aggregator send to the same cache?

I am trying to store aggregate data for long term storage and machine specific data for short term storage.  From what I can tell documentation wise it is possible to do this with two different caches, but from an administration standpoint using a single cache would simplify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible to do this.

Setup the carbon relay to send to both the carbon cache and the carbon aggregator.  Setup the aggregator to send to the same cache the relay is.  The aggregated stats will appear in the cache if properly setup.  I have all these services setup to run on different ports with statsd as a proxy.  So I was able to make all of these changes, start up the relay and aggregation daemons, and then change the port statsd was sending to all with only minimal impact.